DevHub - A Centralized Developer Workspace with Stack Exchange Integration
About DevHub
DevHub is a centralized developer workspace that integrates with Stack Exchange API to provide a seamless development experience.
Features

Stack Overflow integration for viewing questions and answers
GitHub repository management
Real-time tech news feed
Coding challenges with difficulty filters
Developer job listings search

Stack Exchange API Usage

Fetches user profile information
Displays user's questions and answers
Shows reputation and badges
Tracks user contributions

Technical Details

Frontend: Next.js, TypeScript, Tailwind CSS, Framer Motion
Backend: Node.js, Express, MongoDB
Authentication: OAuth 2.0
API Integration: Stack Exchange API v2.3

Development Status
Currently in development phase. Testing Stack Exchange API integration.
Screenshots
[Will be added once the integration is complete]
License
MIT License
Contact
[Your GitHub profile or contact information]
